# Python ORM with sqlalchemy multiple table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and python ORM, so if I'm doing anything wrong here, please let me know.

I have a database with multiple tables (more than 4 on most) and want all of them in the same class. From what I have read so far I can create classes for each db table and make a sqlacademy query the `__table__` for the class. The other main option I can find is create a sql view/query and just map that as a single "table". Each of my tables have a 1:1 relationship.

Is there a way to do a join on multiple (3+) tables to create a single class? Something like:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, join
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

metadata = MetaData()

a = Table('table_a', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
        )
b = Table('table_b', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, ForeignKey('table_a.id'), primary_key=True)
        )
c = Table('table_c', metadata,
        Column('c_id', Integer, ForeignKey('table_a.id'), primary_key=True)
        )

Base = declarative_base()

busObj = join(a, b, c)
#busObj = join(a, b).join(c) # as an alternative

class BusinessObj(Base):
    __table__ = busObj

    def __repr__(self):
        return "BusinessObj {}".format(self.id)
```

When I attempt the above, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$PYTHON_APP_DATA\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "$PYTHON_APP_DATA\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 550, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

The SQL that it generates is, verbaitim:

```
 SELECT "table_a".id AS "table_a_id",
    "table_b".id AS "table_b_id",
    "table_c".user_id AS "table_c_user_id"
FROM "table_c",
    "table_a" 
    JOIN "table_b" ON
```

From the above you can see the issue is that it's not joining table_a and table_b on any fields, and not even thinking about joining table_c at all.

---

EDIT 2: This question was poorly worded and wasn't accurately reflecting the issues I was encountering. I will close this post, but to answer the poorly worded question I had above in case another lost soul stumbles across this:

The correct syntax for what I was looking for was

```
busObj = join(table_a, table_b, onclause=table_a.c.id==table_b.c.id)\
    .join(table_c, onclause=table_a.c.id==table_c.c.user_id)
```

However, when doing that I was encountering an error because I had a recursive table reference. The business object I am working with is `Users` which also has a `created_by` field which references the id of the user that created this first account. You can see the issue.

For right now the above works, with a workaround of not including the foreign key part of the created_by field - but I will have to manually update that field later if/when that field needs to be updated.

Comment: @IljaEverilä You're right, I did some more digging and found the real problem, I had a recursive object - which while still a problem is probably best for a different post.